# Unable to modify or save pdf files

Tags: pdf, preview

When I try to fill a pdf file from the preview app it says "The original document can't be changed, a duplicate has been created". When I try to quit it asks me where I want to save the new document but it will then tell me it is unable to save the file. The preview app will let me click checkboxes and fill text, it will not let me save the modified document.
The file is not locked and I have read/write rights.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What system are you running?